# Why is my baking not working?

Tags: rendering, mesh, shaders, texture-baking, baking

When I try to bake my high poly mesh to a low poly one, it does not visibly insert the deformities to it even after render. I tried fiddling with some values in the shading tab but no dice. After a while of troubleshooting and baking, I started getting notifications that said "circular dependency for image". I don't know if this is part of the problem. I'm a noob at blender so help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: “Circular dependency” means the image is set up to be used to calculate itself, which will not work.

Comment: The *ImageTexture* node that specifies the destination image for the bake *must not* be connected to a shader and *must* be selected (highlighted) in the shader node editor.